# How to customize the pluralization EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to use the interface `IPluralizationService` to customize the pluralization of my entities without success!

Necessary that all entities are pluralized using the [Inflector](https://nuget.org/packages/Inflector/) library.

### Attempts

```
class Config : DbConfiguration
{
    public Config()
    {
        SetPluralizationService(new CustomPluralization());
    }
}

class CustomPluralization : IPluralizationService
{
    public string Pluralize(string word)
    {
        return word.Pluralize();
    }

    public string Singularize(string word)
    {
        return word.Singularize();
    }
}
```

In my context;

`modelBuilder.Configurations.Add<Config>(.. ?? ..)`

Comment: Is it for Code-First? Apparently this approach wouldn't work for Db-First or Model-First [according to this article (section "Customize EF Pluralization")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532202.aspx)

Comment: @IvanAkcheurov This is why EF is trash; so many places and opportunities for us to plug into the library, and they're not supported. (FWIW, I say "EF is trash" as a regular consumer of it, not an outside on-looker)

Answer (score 1):

According to msdn's article [Code-Based Configuration (EF6 onwards)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx) section **[Using DbConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx#Using)**, it is sufficient to simply place your `DbConfiguration` class in the same assembly as your `DbContext` class.

Nevertheless you can specify it manually, as [explained in the article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx#Moving) by using either the config file or an annotation in your `DbContext`.

### Config file:

```xml
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MyNamespace.MyDbConfiguration, MyAssembly">
    <!-- Your EF config -->
</entityFramework>
```

### Annotation:

```cs
[DbConfigurationType("MyNamespace.MyDbConfiguration, MyAssembly")] 
public class MyContextContext : DbContext 
{ 
}
```

Or

```cs
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDbConfiguration))] 
public class MyContextContext : DbContext 
{ 
}
```

#### Note:

These examples are directly from the article I linked